# Event Handler Not Working

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#SomeLink').onclick = 
    function(event)
    {
        alert('test');
    };
```

And this is my markup:

```
<a href='#' id='SomeLink'>
    Some Link
</a>
```

Obviously very simple.  [Here is the jsFiddle for the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/Surfer/fspSJ/).

What is the `onclick` event not firing with a simple dialog?  I'm new to jQuery, and I'm sure it's a very simple thing but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's simply not how [the jQuery API works](http://api.jquery.com/click/). *This* is:

```
$('#SomeLink').click(function(event)
{
    alert('test');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/VZtQn/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the function and pass it as a param to the `.click` function.

One of the key aspects of jscript or any other functional programming language is that you can pass functions as params into other functions.  So, that allows you to do something like this:

```
var funct = 
function(event) 
{ 
    alert('test'); 
};

$('#SomeLink').click(funct)
```